# Make a layout animation before its visibility gone

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to implement animation on one `layout` to move bottom to top, and then make its visibility `GONE`

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_to_top);
linearLayoutAskOptThree.startAnimation(animation);
linearLayoutThree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But the problem is layout visibility gets gone before showing animation, can anybody tell me the solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `AnimationListener` to the `animation` variable and in its [onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation)) method set `linearLayoutThree`'s visibility to `GONE`.